# Bulk Parameterized Inserts

Tags: php, sql, bulkinsert, parameterized-query

I'm trying to switch some hard-coded queries to use parameterized inputs, but I've run into a problem:  How do you format the input for parameterized bulk inserts?

Currently, the code looks like this:

```
$data_insert = "INSERT INTO my_table (field1, field2, field3) ";
$multiple_inserts = false;
while ($my_condition)
{
    if ($multiple_inserts)
    {
        $data_insert .= " UNION ALL ";
    }

    $data_insert .= " SELECT myvalue1, myvalue2, myvalue3 ";
}

$recordset = sqlsrv_query($my_connection, $data_insert);
```

A potential solution (modified from [How to insert an array into a single MySQL Prepared statement w/ PHP and PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629022/how-to-insert-an-array-into-a-single-mysql-prepared-statement-w-php-and-pdo)) appears to be:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO my_table (field1, field2, field3) VALUES ';
$parameters = array();
$data = array();
while ($my_condition)
{
    $parameters[] = '(?, ?, ?)';
    $data[] = value1;
    $data[] = value2;
    $data[] = value3;
}

if (!empty($parameters)) 
{
    $sql .= implode(', ', $parameters);
    $stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($my_connection, $sql, $data);
    sqlsrv_execute($stmt);
}
```

Is there a better way to accomplish a bulk insert with parameterized queries?

Comment: A potential solution, specific to prepared statements, is "single prepare, multiple executions"

Comment: I was trying to avoid doing that to limit the need for transaction-handling.  If any one of the inserts fails, the entire operation should fail.

Comment: If I execute separate statements, I'll have to add a transaction to allow for rolling back should an error occur during the addition of any given row.  A bulk insert does not require a transaction since it will either all succeed or all fail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you have three options.

1. Build once - execute multiple.  Basically, you prepare the insert once for one row, then loop over the rows executing it. Since the SQLSERVER extension doesn't support re-binding of a query after it's been prepared (you need to do [dirty hacks with references](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/cc296201(v=SQL.90).aspx)) that may not be the best option.
2. Build once - execute once.  Basically, you build one giant insert as you said in your example, bind it once, and execute it.  This is a little bit dirty and misses some of the benefits that prepared queries gives.  However, due to the requirement of references from Option 1, I'd do this one.  I think it's cleaner to build a giant query rather than depend on variable references.
3. Build multiple - execute multiple.  Basically, take the method you're doing, and tweak it to re-prepare the query every so many records.  This prevents overly big queries and "batches" the queries.  So something like this:

   ```
   $sql = 'INSERT INTO my_table (field1, field2, field3) VALUES ';
   $parameters = array();
   $data = array();

   $execute = function($params, $data) use ($my_connection, $sql) {
       $query = $sql . implode(', ', $parameters);
       $stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($my_connection, $query, $data);
       sqlsrv_execute($stmt);
   }

   while ($my_condition) {
       $parameters[] = '(?, ?, ?)';
       $data[] = value1;
       $data[] = value2;
       $data[] = value3;
       if (count($parameters) % 25 == 0) {
           //Flush every 25 records
           $execute($parameters, $data);
           $parameters = array();
           $data = array();
       }
   }
   if (!empty($parameters))  {
       $execute($sql, $parameters, $data);
   }
   ```

Either method will suffice.  Do what you think fits your requirements best...

Comment: Just for clarification:  In both Option 2 and 3, the SQL statement would look something like this (if it were to be printed to screen):  `INSERT INTO mytable (field1, field2, field3) VALUES (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), etc.` to be filled in by the array passed to it.  Is that correct?

Comment: @Zac: Yes, that's correct.  The 3rd would have at most 25 of the groups (you could tweak that depending on data size).  The 2nd would have as many as you have rows...

Comment: All values are inserted as `PDO::PARAM_STR`, aren't they ?  
How to specify the types ?

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use "prepare once, execute multiple" method. I know you want it to either all fail or all work, but it's not exactly hard to handle that with transactions:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.commit.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.rollback.php

Comment: Its not difficult, but it adds a level of complexity to this code that isn't really needed.  Bulk Inserts are the most elegant solution to my problem, its just a matter of syntax that I wasn't sure of.

Comment: Plus this is using the native `sqlsrv` extension which isn't the sanest thing in the world (if he was using PDO, possibly, but the native sqlsrv extension is lacking in quite a few areas)...

Comment: if the point of this is to move to paramaterised queries, why not move to PDO at the same time?

as for the "complexity" it's not exactly hard to add a check if a call to execute() fails, and if so do a rollback() and then any other error handling you need.

Comment: Because PDO no longer supports using the SQL Server (TDS) drivers and creating a special case for connecting to this database is not a viable option (there is a global connection string already established that works with both the mssql_ and sqlsrv_ extensions, but not with PDO using ODBC).

Comment: @ZacHowland I would not say the most elegant solution, I would maybe say the easiest. For me _Prepare once / Execute multiple_ is the most elegant.