# MySQLi : Inserting multiple rows with one prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I made a script that creates a raw query string and then inserts the hundreds of rows in one statement. It works but does not offer the protections that prepared statements do. I then modified my script to add prepared statements. It works however, it is significantly slower. The script with prepared statements takes much longer to insert the rows than the raw query script, due to the script running through each prepared insert statement one row at a time rather than inserting hundred of rows at a time.

Here's a snippet of the prepared statement code:

```
for( $j = 0; $j < $abilitiesMax - 2; $j++ ){
  $stmtAbility->bind_param('iiiii', $abilityArray[$i]["match_id"] , $abilityArray[$i]["player_slot"],
  $abilityArray[$i][$j]["ability"], $abilityArray[$i][$j]["time"], $abilityArray[$i][$j]["level"] );

  if(  !($stmtAbility->execute()) ){      
   echo "<p>$db->error</p>";
   echo "<p>ERROR: when trying to insert abilities query</p>";
  }
}
```

It gets the job done but only after hundreds upon hundreds of inserts. Is there a way to bind lists or arrays to the bind_param() arguments and just run the $stmtAbility->execute one time or some other method that can speed up performance.

Sorry if this has been asked and answered before. I looked around for a while and found some similar questions but nothing that answered what I was asking for explicitly.

Comment: At least strongly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659317/bulk-parameterized-inserts ?

Comment: You might want to bind the parameters before the loop and then set the bound variables' values within it.

Comment: @MichaelRushton I was thinking something similar, although I doubt that the calls to `bind_param` are the bottleneck. Most of the overhead is probably in `execute()`.

Comment: As long as you have your conventional query properly formatted, it is as safe as prepared one.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to prepare a bulk insert statement query by constructing it on the fly, but it takes a few tricks.  The most important bits are using `str_pad()` to construct a query string of variable length, and using `call_user_func_array()` to call `bind_param()` with a variable number of parameters.

```
function insertBulkPrepared($db, $table, $fields, $types, $values) {
    $chunklength = 500;
    $fieldcount = count($fields);
    $fieldnames = '`'.join('`, `', $fields).'`';
    $prefix = "INSERT INTO `$table` ($fieldnames) VALUES ";
    $params = '(' . str_pad('', 3*$fieldcount - 2, '?, ') . '), ';
    $inserted = 0;

    foreach (array_chunk($values, $fieldcount*$chunklength) as $group) {
        $length = count($group);
        if ($inserted != $length) {
            if ($inserted) $stmt->close();
            $records = $length / $fieldcount;
            $query = $prefix . str_pad('', 3*$length + 2*($records - 1), $params);
            #echo "\n<br>Preparing '" . $query . "'";
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
            if (!$stmt) return false;
            $binding = str_pad('', $length, $types);
            $inserted = $length;
        }

        array_unshift($group, $binding);
        #echo "\n<br>Binding " . var_export($group, true);
        $bound = call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $group);
        if (!$bound) return false;
        if (!$stmt->execute()) return false;
    }

    if ($inserted) $stmt->close();
    return true;
}
```

This function takes your `$db` as a `mysqli` instance, a table name, an array of field names, and a flat array of references to values.  It inserts up to 500 records per query, re-using prepared statements when possible.  It returns `true` if all of the inserts succeeded, or `false` if any of them failed.  Caveats:

- The table and field names are not escaped; I leave it up to you to ensure that they don't contain backticks.  Fortunately, they should never come from user input.
- If the length of `$values` is not an even multiple of the length of `$fields`, the final chunk will probably fail at the preparation stage.
- Likewise, the length of the `$types` parameter should match the length of `$fields` in most cases, particularly when some of them differ.
- It doesn't distinguish between the three ways to fail.  It also don't keep track of how many inserts succeeded, nor does it attempt to continue after an error.

With this function defined, your example code can be replaced with something like:

```
$inserts = array();
for ($j = 0; $j < $abilitiesMax - 2; $j++) {
    $inserts[] = &$abilityArray[$i]['match_id'];
    $inserts[] = &$abilityArray[$i]['player_slot'];
    $inserts[] = &$abilityArray[$i][$j]['ability'];
    $inserts[] = &$abilityArray[$i][$j]['time'];
    $inserts[] = &$abilityArray[$i][$j]['level'];
}

$fields = array('match_id', 'player_slot', 'ability', 'time', 'level');
$result = insertBulkPrepared($db, 'abilities', $fields, 'iiiii', $inserts);
if (!$result) {
    echo "<p>$db->error</p>";
    echo "<p>ERROR: when trying to insert abilities query</p>";
}
```

Those ampersands are important, because `mysqli_stmt::bind_param` expects references, which aren't provided by `call_user_func_array` in recent versions of PHP.

You didn't give us the original prepared statement, so you probably need to adjust the table and field names.  It also looks like your code sits inside a loop over `$i`; in that case, only the `for` loop needs to be inside the outer loop.  If you take the other lines outside the loop, you will use a bit more memory constructing the `$inserts` array, in return for much more efficient bulk inserts.

It's also possible to rewrite `insertBulkPrepared()` to accept a multi-dimensional array, eliminating one source of potential error, but that requires flattening the array after chunking it.

Comment: Handy function! maybe you can make it even better if you combine the function params: $fields, $types & $values into one param $records that reads a key => value array.