# How to insert nested arrays in MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I have an array that represents a quiz created by my app. Here I've got the question title, type of question and it's answers in a nested array.

Here's an example of the array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [options] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [valid] => 
                            [content] => Answer 1
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [valid] => 
                            [content] => Answer 2
                        )

                    [2] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [valid] => 
                            [content] => Answer 3
                        )

                )

            [content] => Question 1
            [type] => radios
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [options] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [valid] => 
                            [content] => Answer 1
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [valid] => 
                            [content] => Answer 2
                        )

                    [2] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [valid] => 
                            [content] => Answer 3
                        )

                )

            [content] => Question 2
            [type] => radios
        )

)
```

Right now my code looks like this:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$test = json_decode($_POST['test']);

$con=mysqli_connect("Localhost","root","","test");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
```

This covers the connection to the database.
While doing my research I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15013211/how-to-insert-array-of-data-into-mysql-using-php) question. It covers the basic principles of the insert process, but I have a problem while trying to implement the solution:

I have two tables. A question table and an options table. The nested array 'options' in my data needs to be inserted in the options table and each one of its positions referenced to the main question. How can I do this, while inserting the 'content' and the 'type' fields into the question table?

EDIT: I tried this code but it's currently not working. How could I adapt it?

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO question (content, type) values ";

$valuesArr = array();
    foreach($test as $row){

    $content = mysql_real_escape_string( $row['content'] );
    $type = mysql_real_escape_string( $row['type'] );

$valuesArr[] = "('$content', '$type')";
}

$sql .= implode(',', $valuesArr);
```

EDIT: My table structure:

**Question**

- ID (PK)
- Content
- Type

**Options**

- ID (PK)
- Question_ID (FK)
- Content

Comment: Your Question and Options Table structure?, you want to store ids from option table to respective question?

Comment: @boom_Shiva I want to reference the options to its questions by ID. If there is a better way to do this, let me know please. Edited question.

Comment: Aren't you storing the value for Valid field for Options, the one there in your Object?, I've updated the answer

Comment: @boom_Shiva It is not needed right now. After I learn how to store this I will be storing it when the time comes.

Comment: So make the modifications as per your requirement for fields in the answer, main logic would be same.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44171/discussion-between-jean-carlos-suarez-marranzini-and-boom-shiva)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table structure is:

**Question**         **Options**

`ID (PK)`           `ID (PK)`

`Content`           `Question_ID (FK)`

`Type`              `Content`

I've taken the whole array as `$questions` (the object you pasted in your question)

```
foreach( $questions as $question ){
  $options = $question->options;
  $options_id = array();
  $question_query = "INSERT INTO questions (Content, Type) VALUES ({$question->content}, {$question->type})";
  if( !mysqli_query($con, $question_query) ){ echo "Query failed"; return; }
  $question_id= mysqli_insert_id();
  foreach($options as $option){
      $options_query = "INSERT INTO options (Question_ID, Content, Valid) VALUES ({$question_id}, {$option->content}, {$option->valid})";
      if( mysqli_query($con, $options_query) ){
       $options_id[] = mysqli_insert_id();
      }
  }

  if($options_id){
    //Do something or store options and question id
    var_dump($options_id); //just to check
  }
}
```