# Pdo multiple row insert issue

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo

[image]

I'm having some problem with inserting multiple rows in mysql with pdo prepare statements.

The insert works but only once.

I have tried to put the query before the foreach, but same problem.

```
  $product_id = $_POST['id'];
  if (isset($_POST['product_attribute'])){
        $att_id = array();

    foreach ($_POST['product_attribute'] as $product_attribute) {

      $att_id[] = $product_attribute['attribute_id'];

      if ($product_attribute['attribute_id']) {
          $stmt = $database->prepare("DELETE FROM product_attribute WHERE product_id =:product_id AND attribute_id=:attribute_id");
          $stmt->bindParam(':product_id', $product_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
          $stmt->bindParam(':attribute_id',  $product_attribute['attribute_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
          $stmt->execute();


        foreach ($product_attribute['product_attribute_description'] as $product_attribute_description) {
          $stmt = $database->prepare("INSERT INTO product_attribute SET product_id=:product_id, product_code=:product_code, attribute_id=:attribute_id, `text`=:atext");
          $stmt->bindParam(':product_id', $product_id,  PDO::PARAM_INT);
          $stmt->bindParam(':product_code', $_POST['codprodus'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
          $stmt->bindParam(':attribute_id', $product_attribute['attribute_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
          $stmt->bindParam(':atext',  $product_attribute_description['text'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
          $stmt->execute();

        }
      }
    }

    $vals = implode( ",", $att_id );
    $stmt = $database->prepare("DELETE FROM product_attribute WHERE product_id =:product_id AND attribute_id NOT IN(:vals)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':product_id', $product_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':vals', $vals, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();

  }else {
    $stmt = $database->prepare("DELETE FROM product_attribute WHERE product_id =:product_id");
    $stmt->bindParam(':product_id',  $product_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
  }
```

Print_r($_POST['product_attribute'] :

```
Array([103] => Array(
            [attribute_id] => 103
            [product_attribute_description] => Array
                (
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [text] => 56
                        )

                )

        )

    [102] => Array
        (
            [attribute_id] => 102
            [product_attribute_description] => Array
                (
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [text] => da
                        )

                )

        )

    [104] => Array
        (
            [attribute_id] => 104
            [product_attribute_description] => Array
                (
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [text] => da
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

And here is my product_attribute table schema.

```
product_id      int(11)     NO  PRI         
attribute_id    int(11)     NO  PRI         
product_code    int(11)     NO          
text            text        NO
```

Comment: Try removing the `['text']` from `$product_attribute_description['text']` since you're doing `as $product_attribute_description`

Comment: if i remove it the result will be array

Comment: Have you tried `implode()`?

Comment: See this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/q/7055257/ using `implode()`.

Comment: Still the same result

Comment: What's inside `$_POST['product_attribute']`?

Comment: Se my edited question

Comment: Move the pdo prepare statement to before "for" block.

Comment: Tried and the same issue

Comment: With my old and deprecated mysql_query this works

Comment: I would use 'bindValue' rather than 'bindParam'. I have found that 'foreach' loops can be 'interesting' as regards which 'references' actually get 'bound' to the prepared statement inside the loop. For this reason i always use 'bindValue unless using one of the 'blob' types. I then explicitly decalare the variable and bind to that.

Comment: Yes, but how can this fix my insert problem ?

Comment: Have you tried using 'bandValue'? It is easy to try and you are no worse off. If it still doesn't work then there may be other issues to be checked. I will setup a test here if required.

Comment: Tried with bindValue and i got the same result.. Is inserting just the first key

Comment: Please update your question with the 'product_attribute' table definition. Also, i cannot spot what  the variable '$product_id' and '$product_code' is set to?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72245/discussion-between-speedy-and-ryan-vincent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is deleting the newly inserted rows. Comment it out and all is fine.

```
/*
$vals = implode( ",", $att_id );
$stmt = $database->prepare("DELETE FROM product_attribute WHERE product_id =:product_id AND attribute_id NOT IN(:vals)");
$stmt->bindValue(':product_id', $product_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(':vals', $vals, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
*/
```

Comment: @speedy, thanks for that - was glad to assist in getting it running.