# php PDO insert batch multiple rows with placeholders

Tags: php, insert, pdo, bulkinsert

I am looking to do multiple inserts using PHP PDO.

The closest answer I have found is this one

**[how-to-insert-an-array-into-a-single-mysql-prepared-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629022/how-to-insert-an-array-into-a-single-mysql-prepared-statement-w-php-and-pdo)**

However the example thats been given uses ?? instead of real placeholders.

I have looked at the examples on the PHP doc site for place holders

**[php.net pdo.prepared-statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)**

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (:name, :value)");
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
$stmt->bindParam(':value', $value);
```

Now lets say I wanted to achieve the above but with an array

```
$valuesToInsert = array(
  0 => array('name' => 'Robert', 'value' => 'some value'),
  1 => array('name' -> 'Louise', 'value' => 'another value')
);
```

**How would I go about it with PDO and multiple inserts per transaction?**

I imagine it would start of with a loop?

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (:name, :value)");

foreach($valuesToInsert as $insertRow){

    // now loop through each inner array to match binded values
    foreach($insertRow as $column => value){
        $stmt->bindParam(":{$column}", value);
    }
}
$stmt->execute();
```

However the above does not work but hopefully will demonstrate what im trying to achieve

Comment: you need to execute inside the loop. otherwise you're just overwriting the bound parameter and end up binding only the LAST value.

Comment: however if I execute then that will do the DB transaction one row at a time?  Im trying to do it in batch

Comment: yes, but if you're trying to emulate the mysql extended `insert ... values (...), (...), (...)` insert syntax, this is not how you go about it. you'd have to pre-build a query statement that has a placeholder for every set of values you're inserting, prepare it, bind parameters, then execute. you'd end up doing just as much work as running a single prepared insert multiple times.

Comment: I'm inserting some 40 or 50k rows at a time. I need to do it in batch.  Its the DB transaction that takes up the time.

Comment: Then wrap the entire thing in a single transaction using PDO::beginTransaction() / PDO::commit() and execute queries as mentioned by @MarcB.

Comment: JFYI: `??` are **real** placeholders and `:name` are fake ones.

Comment: how do I do PDO::beginTransaction() / PDO::commit()

Answer (score 30, accepted):

First of all, `?` symbols *are* real place-holders (most drivers allow to use both syntaxes, positional and named place-holders). Secondly, prepared statements are nothing but a tool to inject raw input into SQL statements—the syntax of the SQL statement itself is unaffected. You already have all the elements you need:

- How to insert multiple rows with a single query
- How to generate SQL dynamically
- How to use prepared statements with named place-holders.

It's fairly trivial to combine them all:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO table (memberID, programID) VALUES ';
$insertQuery = [];
$insertData = [];
$n = 0;
foreach ($data as $row) {
    $insertQuery[] = '(:memberID' . $n . ', :programID' . $n . ')';
    $insertData['memberID' . $n] = $memberid;
    $insertData['programID' . $n] = $row;
    $n++;
}

if (!empty($insertQuery)) {
    $sql .= implode(', ', $insertQuery);
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($insertData);
}
```

Comment: Note that on large data sets you will hit a limit with SQL **VALUES** clause _(around 1 000 rows)_ and you might have to limit batch size.  I noticed that increasing the batch size is not always performant, so test with different batch sizes. Make sure your named placeholders are not using numbers in the end other than the $n to avoid conflicts.

Comment: See also `array_chunk`

Comment: Experiment results: using `array_chunk` with 100 rows realized a 2x speed up versus normal for loop on InnoDB using transactions. Larger batches did not go any faster.

Answer (score 8):

I'm assuming you are using InnoDB so this answer is only valid for that engine (or any other transaction-capable engine, meaning MyISAM isn't included).

By default InnoDB runs in auto-commit mode. That means each query is treated as its own contained transaction.

To translate that to something us mortals can understand, it means that every INSERT query you issue will force hard-disk to commit it by confirming it wrote down the query information. 
Considering how mechanical hard-disks are super slow since their input-output operation per second is low (if I'm not mistaken, the average is 300ish IO's), it means your 50 000 queries will be - well, super slow.

So what do you do? You commit all of your 50k queries in a single transaction. It might not be the best solution for various purposes but it'll be fast.

You do it like this:

```
$dbh->beginTransaction();

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (:name, :value)");

foreach($valuesToInsert as $insertRow)
{    
    // now loop through each inner array to match bound values
    foreach($insertRow as $column => value)
    {
        $stmt->bindParam(":$column", value);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}


$dbh->commit();
```

Comment: I have about 50k rows to insert and was going to do it in batches of 25.  I will try this example as it looks like it could be what im looking for.

Comment: This answer is correct but it doesn't talk about MySQL's multiple-insert syntax which is, in my experience, what can really speed up large batches.

Comment: For the best performance, `LOAD DATA INFILE` is still the fastest option and constructing a file to be used with `LOAD DATA INFILE` should be fairly straightforward. I forgot to add that to the answer, and as @ÁlvaroG.Vicario mentioned - `INSERT INTO .... VALUES..` is faster than executing a prepared statement in the loop.

Comment: The 'value' variable are missing dollar signs :)

Answer (score 1):

A little modifications in solution provided by N.B 
$stmt->execute() should be outside of inner loop because you may have one or more columns that need to bind before calling $stmt->execute() else you 'll get exception "Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of token".
2nd "value" variable were missing dollar signs.

```
function batchinsert($sql,$params){
    try { 
                db->beginTransaction(); 

                $stmt = db->prepare($sql);

                foreach($params as $row)
                {    
                    // now loop through each inner array to match bound values
                    foreach($row as $column => $value)
                    {                           
                        $stmt->bindParam(":$column", $value);                           
                    }
                    $stmt->execute();
                }                                       
                db->commit();                   

        } catch(PDOExecption $e) {
            $db->rollback();                
        }
}
```

Test:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `test`(`name`, `value`) VALUES (:name, :value)" ;

$data = array();    

array_push($data, array('name'=>'Name1','value'=>'Value1')); 

array_push($data, array('name'=>'Name2','value'=>'Value2')); 

array_push($data, array('name'=>'Name3','value'=>'Value3')); 

array_push($data, array('name'=>'Name4','value'=>'Value4')); 

array_push($data, array('name'=>'Name5','value'=>'Value5')); 

batchinsert($sql,$data);
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code was actually ok, but had a problem in `$stmt->bindParam(":$column", value);` It should be `$stmt->bindValue(":{$column}", $value);` and it will work perfectly. This will assist others in future.

Full code:

```
foreach($params as $row)
{ 
    // now loop through each inner array to match bound values
    foreach($row as $column => $value)
    { 
        $stmt->bindValue(":{$column}", $value); //EDIT
    }
    // Execute statement to add to transaction
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: There is not a single problem with this part of syntax. Your suggestion is superfluous and misleading.

Answer (score -4):

Move execute inside of the loop.

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (:name, :value)");
foreach($valuesToInsert as $insertRow)
{
    $stmt->execute($insertRow);    
}
```

**If you experience any problems with this such recommended way, you have to ask a question, describing these certain problems.**

Comment: i dont think the above is doing it in batch looks like it does one at a time?

Comment: This isn't a batch insert, you're very clearly reusing the same SQL statement multiple times per row, but it's still doing a single insert at a time.