# Bulk insert using PDO and PHP variable containing all database values

Tags: php, pdo, bulkinsert

I am new to PHP and am trying to update a deprecated code from mysql to PDO.

Considering that the variable $insert contains all values to bulk insert such as:

```
('82817cf5-52be-4ee4-953c-d3f4ed1459b0','1','EM3X001P.1a','04.03.10.42.00.02'),
('82817cf5-52be-4ee4-953c-d3f4ed1459b0','2','EM3X001P.2a','04.03.10.33.00.02'),
```

...etc 13k lines to insert

here is the deprecated code:

```
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("IPXTools") or die(mysql_error());

if ($insert != '')
{
  $insert = "INSERT INTO IPXTools.MSSWireList (ID,Record,VlookupNode,HostWireLocation) VALUES ".$insert;
  $insert .= "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Record=VALUES(Record),VlookupNode=VALUES(VlookupNode),HostWireLocation=VALUES(HostWireLocation)";

  mysql_query($insert) or die(mysql_error());
  $insert = '';
}
```

here is the new code:

```
try 
{
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);    
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);    //set the PDO error mode to exception

    // prepare sql and bind parameters
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO IPXTools.MSSWireList (ID, Record, VlookupNode, HostWireLocation) 
    VALUES (:ID, :Record, :VlookupNode, :HostWireLocation)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':ID', $ID);
    $stmt->bindParam(':Record', $Record);
    $stmt->bindParam(':VlookupNode', $VlookupNode);
    $stmt->bindParam(':HostWireLocation', $HostWireLocation);    

    // insert a row
    // loop through all values inside the $insert variable??????? how?
    $stmt->execute();
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
     echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
```

During my research I found an excellent post:
[PDO Prepared Inserts multiple rows in single query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176352/pdo-prepared-inserts-multiple-rows-in-single-query)

One method says I would have to change my $insert variable to include all the field names.
And other method says I dont have to do that. I am looking at Chris M. suggestion:

> The Accepted Answer by Herbert Balagtas works well when the $data array is small. With larger $data arrays the array_merge function becomes prohibitively slow. My test file to create the $data array has 28 cols and is about 80,000 lines. The final script took 41s to complete

but I didnt understand what he is doing and I am trying to adapt my code to his. The PHP sintax is new to me so I am strugling with handling the arrays, etc...

I guess the starting point would be the variable $insert which contains all the database values I need.
Do I need to modify my $insert variable to include the field names?
Or I could just use its content and extract the values (how?) and include the values in a loop statement? (that would probably execute my 13k rows one at at time)

Thank you

Comment: @JayBlanchard I don't see him using any `mysql_*` at all.

Comment: Your code looks fine, and you haven't actually posted any question. As far as the vague concerns raised in the linked question, that guy had issues because he did a dumb thing that: 1. Is unrelated to PDO. 2. You are not doing and don't need to do.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Yeah but that's the deprecated code he's trying to update to instead use PDO.

Comment: Ah, that wasn't clear in the first edit @PatrickGregorio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 13k records to insert, it is good for performance to do not use prepared SQL statement. Just generate SQL query in format like this:

```
INSERT INTO IPXTools.MSSWireList 
(ID, Record, VlookupNode, HostWireLocation) 
VALUES 
('id1', 'r1', 'node1', 'location1'),
('id2', 'r2', 'node2', 'location2'),
...
('id13000', 'r13000', 'node13000', 'location13000');
```

What you may do for it - use maner of your legacy code. Your `try` block will looks loke this:

```
try 
{
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);    
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $stmt = $conn->exec($insert);
}
```

Comment: thanks man. That is exactly what I needed. Just to execute the command I had before in PDO. I thought I had to do all the binding. The only problem is that I am getting the error below which I am researching now:

Warning: PDO::exec(): MySQL server has gone away in C:\xampp\htdocs\angular\IPXTool\version001\php\IPXTool_Admin_MSS_Ingest.php on line 162

Warning: PDO::exec(): Error reading result set's header in C:\xampp\htdocs\angular\IPXTool\version001\php\IPXTool_Admin_MSS_Ingest.php on line 162
Error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone awayStatus::Ingested WireList.

Comment: just changed the max_allowed_packet inside my.ini in MySQL and restarted the service. Thanks you!

Comment: @mnv: I see that a separate prepared statement and execute for each data row is bad for performance, but what about using one prepared statement for all the data rows, as suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15070222/2737565 After all, prepared statements have the huge benefit of preventing SQL injection...

Comment: @Alexander Jank you may try that way for 100k+ records and compare execution time with my approach. Difference will be 10+ times, because linking data in PDO is heavy process.